# Splitting string into substring in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, xcode7

I have a small doubt on splitting a string into substring.
I want to display State and Country name in one label. i have a string in a  service coming from json file "FullAddress": "New Windsor,New York,USA". i want only New York,USA to display in a label.

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?  You haven't read the `NSString` class reference yet, and you want us to recite it to you?

Comment: Can you please share json response you are getting ?

Answer (score 4):

Use this and get your desire `String` from `Array` element 1 and 2

```
NSArray *strings = [FullAddress componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

Comment: Rather than 1 and 2 it's probably `[array count] - 2` and `[array count] -1`.

Answer (score 0):

Please Use this code it will be help you out

```
NSString *fullAddress=@"New Windsor,New York,USA";

    NSRange range=[fullAddress rangeOfString:@","];
    if (range.location!=NSNotFound) {
        NSString *string=[fullAddress substringFromIndex:range.location+range.length];//this is address you want
        NSLog(@"%@",string);
    }
```